# how to merge two pouch DB data as in one couch DB

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, couchdb-futon, relational-pouch

This is my Pouch DB data for user "A"

{"people": [{"id": 1,"dept_id": 3,"user": "A",},{"id":2 ,"dept_id": 1,"user": "B",},{"id": 3,"dept_id": 1,"user": "C",}]}

This is my pouch DB data for user "B"

{"people": [{"id": 1,"dept_id": 1,"user": "A"},{"id":2 ,"dept_id": 4,"user": "B"},{"id": 3,"dept_id": 1,"user": "C"}]}

When updating both on the couch, last updated DB content either "A"s DB or "B"s DB which are updated last is stored in Couch. 
I couldn't merge these to in couch DB.
**Is it possible to perform partial document updates??**
Please help me. I'm new to this pouch and couch DB.

Comment: You must do this manually. See [Conflict Management](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/conflicts.html).

Comment: conflict management says about the DB's from the couch. how to partially update documents from the pouch to couch

Comment: There are no partial updates in the CouchDB/PouchDB universe. All updates must be complete.